# Header icon not showing in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, icons

if you can see here http://www.elbaplasticfree.it, in the header left you can see the logo and in the right (if you not use IE8) you can see 4 icons (also with IE10 you can see them).

I have tried anything but with IE8 it's impossible to show them :(

Please, can you give me some suggestions? I do not know what to do...

Thanks,
bye!

Francesco

Comment: How do you show them normally? Just with <img src=""> or do you use JS or PHP to create it? Maybe you could post the CSS for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove width="100%" attributes from IMGs.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much! :) I'm crazy for this..
You know why? because i have another website with images set on 100% width and IE8 show them regularly... very strange...
Sorry i can give you +1 because i need to have 15 of reputation!
Thanks very much!
bye!

Answer (score 0):

Try to define width and height attributes as plain numbers (without % or px). Also: If you you attribute based selectors for those images in your CSS it probably won't work in old browsers.

Comment: Hi, 
the comment above applies also to you :)

Thanks,
bye!

Comment: Just mark the right answer then. You can do that by clicking the icon for it left of this box.

Comment: No problem. Note though, that only one answer can be the right on. So if you mark one as right it will remove the other one.